# Alternate to using last_value and first_value in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am converting my SQL queries from SQL server to be able to run in AWS Athena. There are a bunch of queries that use `first_value()` and `last_value()` which work correctly in SQL server. But, when I convert the same query to run against data in AWS Athena, I get different results every time I run the query. I tried to change the different partition by parameters for following, preceding, desc, asc, etc., but it never yields the same results when I run the query consecutive times.

Has anyone else faced this same issue? If yes, how were you able to resolve this issue?

Example of a query I am running is as follows:

```
select distinct a.col1, a.col2, 
last_value(a.col3) over (partition by a.col1, a.col2 order by a.col1,a.col2  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as col3
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON (a.col1 = b.col1
AND a.col2 = b.col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide "valid" value `ORDER BY` clause ([docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html)):

> The `ORDER BY` clause determines the order in which input rows will be processed by the window function. If `ORDER BY` is not specified, the ordering is undefined.

If it is not provided - Athena (Presto/Trino) does not have/maintain any "predifined"/"natural" order (the same will go for grouping queries).

The order you are providing in:

```sql
partition by a.col1, a.col2 order by a.col1,a.col2
```

Is effectively useless since partition already will contain values only with the same `col1` and `col2`. You need to use some extra column for ordering (usually some kind of unique timestamp is a good candidate).

Note that the fact the you observe "correct" behaviour in SQL Server is actually only by chance and is not guaranteed, since (AFAIK) there is [no default ordering](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186898) there too.